# prevent d3 zoom moving text in svg to different position to the rest of the svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using d3 to zoom in on an svg element. There is text on the svg which is then moving to the top left of the screen when I zoom in on the svg. I know this is due to the fact the text has a `transform` property. Does anyone know how to get arrow d this issue.

**SVG**

```
<circle id="c-1" class="st6 big-circle" cx="319.4" cy="277" r="26"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 313.3557 284.8708)" class="st1 st7 st8">4</text>
```

**D3/JS**

```
svg = d3.select("svg")
  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 5])
    .on("zoom", function() {
      var e = d3.event,
      tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[0]))
      ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[1]));
      zoom.translate([tx, ty]);
      svg.selectAll("*").attr("transform", [
        "translate(" + [tx, ty] + ")",
        "scale(" + e.scale + ")"
      ].join(" "));
  });
    svg.call(zoom);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `text` element in a `g` tag...

```
<circle id="c-1" class="st6 big-circle" cx="319.4" cy="277" r="26"/>
<g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 313.3557 284.8708)" class="st1 st7 st8">4</text>
</g>
```

And then select everything except the `text` element to apply the transformation:

```
svg.selectAll("*:not(text)").attr("transform", [
    "translate(" + [tx, ty] + ")",
    "scale(" + e.scale + ")"
  ].join(" "));
```